# Udt as SQL Server SP parameter coming through empty

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I've got a bit of a problem that I just cannot fathom. I'm passing a user defined table type as a parameter from C# to a SQL Server stored procedure and always end up with 0 rows in the table once it reaches the SP. The .NET code is Framework 4.7, the SQL Server is hosted in Azure.

The SP definition is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ImportData]
    @ImportData udt_ImportData READONLY
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.DEBUG ([Key], [Value])
         SELECT 'IMPORTDATA',
                (SELECT COUNT(1)
                   FROM @ImportData);

    ...
RETURN 0
```

The udt is defined as

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_ImportData] AS TABLE
(
    RecordId INT,
    RecordName NVARCHAR(100)
);
```

The code I'm calling the SP with is

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("RecordId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("RecordName", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    table.Rows.Add(row["RecordId"], row["RecordName"]);
}

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("sp_ImportData", connection);
    SqlParameter tvpParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImportData", table);
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.udt_ImportData";

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Whilst debugging, I've checked that there actually are data rows in the table variable before it's attached as a parameter value. I've also inserted some debugging code into the SP to log out the number of rows in the @ImportData table once it's passed in. This always comes out as zero. I've tried using and not using the @ symbol in the parameter name, I've tried renaming the parameter (in case it was a reserved word that I wasn't aware of). I've tried adding and removing the "dbo." prefix to the udt name in C# but none of these have worked.

If anyone could help, I'd be very appreciative; this is driving me mad! I'm sure it's something quite small that I'm not seeing!

Comment: It depends on the scenario I'm running, but generally around 40,000. Is there a limit?

Comment: I don't think the content of the stored procedure is relevant to the question; I've updated it with the debug line I'm using though. I can call it from SSMS with no problem; all works. I'm almost certain the issue is around the way I'm calling the SP from C#.

Comment: You debugged through the code and explicitly checked the value of `table.Rows.Count` on `command.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: The one thing I see missing from your c# code is `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`, but I'm not sure that's the problem. Also, Instead of `AddWithValue` you can do `Add("@ImportData", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = table;` - but I'm quite sure that's not the problem.

Comment: You, sir (@ZoharPeled) are a genius! I'd missed out the CommandType. I've put that in and all works correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not really... Just somone who have seen (and done) the very same mistake before :-). Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment - you didn't specify the command type in your c# code. The default value of the `CommandType` property is `CommandType.Text` - that fits inline sql but not stored procedures, so you need to specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. While we are at it, you don't have to specify the parameter's type name, and you really [should avoid using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
One more thing - `SqlCommand` also implements the `IDisposable` interface, so it also should be used inside a `using` statement:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand("sp_ImportData", connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@ImportData", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = table;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```